# Perl: scope and allocation of a named variable

Tags: perl

Here is a little sample.

```
my %X = ();

for (my $i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++)
{
    $X {$i} = [$i .. 4];  # the assignment: reference to an unnamed array
}

# this is just for output - you can ignore it
foreach (sort keys %X)
{
    print "\n" . $_ . " = ";
    foreach (@{$X {$_}})
    {
        print $_;
    }
}
```

The output is like expected.

```
0 = 01234
1 = 1234
2 = 234
3 = 34
4 = 4
```

If I use a local variable for the assignment it will produce the same output - thats ok!
The memory for the list is always reallocated and not overwritten because @l is always new. There is still a reference to it in %X so no release is possible(or however the memory-managment in perl is working - I dont know).

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++)
{
  my @l = ($i .. 4);  # inside
  $X {$i} = \@l;
}
```

But can I produce the same output from above with using an outside variable?

Is that possible with some allocation trick - like to give it a new memory but not garbage the old one?

```
my %X = ();
my @l;  # outside
for (my $i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++)
{
    @l = ($i .. 4);
    $X {$i} = \@l;
}
```

All hash-elements now the the content of the last loop.

```
0 = 4
1 = 4
2 = 4
3 = 4
4 = 4
```

Is it possible to get the output from the beginning with the outer variable?

Comment: `$X{$i} = [@l]`

Comment: If you store a reference to the array, the reference stays the same.

Comment: `@{$X {$i}} = @l;` would also work.

Comment: `@{ $X{$i} } = @l;` works because it's short for `@{ $X{$i} //= [] } = @l;`. `X{$i} = [ @l ];` is far clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible for each value of `%X` to be a reference to a different array, while at the same time all being a reference to the same array.

If you want each value of `%X` to be a reference to a same array, go ahead an allocate a single array outside of the loop.

If you want each value of `%X` to be a reference to a different array, you'll need to allocate a new array for each pass through the loop. This can be a named one (created using `my`), or an anonymous one (created using `[ ]`).

---

If you simply wanted to use the values within the outside `@l` so that every referenced array initially has the same value, you could use

```
my @a = @l;
$X{$i} = \@l;
```

or

```
$X{$i} = [ @l ];
```